# Get node path for different domain

Tags: 7, domain-access

I have a series of nodes which are published on up to 7 different domains on the same single Drupal 7 install. Whilst I can use `url('node/12345');` for nodes published to the current domain, I would like to create href links to the these nodes and have them link to the correct domain path.

At the moment, nodes that are not published to the current domain are just giving me `href="/12345"`.

How do I get the URL for nodes that aren't in the current domain?

Comment: you could use (without path-alias) http://otherdomain.com/node/12345

Comment: @rémy Thank you, that would work, but surely there is a way to get the path alias as well given I know the domain ID and node ID?

Comment: I'm assuming you use the Domain Access module since you tagged your question as such. Please mention it in your question as well so this vital information is not missed. Did you read the module's README.txt and INSTALL.txt, and include its settings.inc in your settings.php? Domain Access is a complex module but the documentation included is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `drupal_get_path_alias('node/12345')` ([see docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7.x)) and then exchange the domain name.